# another libgit2-newbie question: How do I update a sub-directory?

Tags: git, subdirectory, libgit2

Your newbie is now trying to add a file to a sub-directory using libgit2. What I would like is some feedback as to whether I understand what I need to do.

I have managed to create some files in the top level directory. I have also managed to create a sub-directory, with the sub-directory in the top level directory, and a file in the sub-directory.

I am doing all this in a bare repository, with libgit2 tree objects for each directory, created and recreated using the treebuilder.

But when I try creating a new file in the sub-directory, it goes into the top-level directory. In fact, what I expected to go in the sub-directory all winds up in the top-level directory.

So, it seems to me that:

- what I am doing "in the sub-directory" is creating a new directory with the existing contents plus my new file.
- what I then need to do is to then create a new top-level directory that contains (a) all of the contents of the existing top-level directory except (b) my newly created sub-directory in place of the old sub-directory.

Presumably then, to update any file anywhere in the file hierarchy, I need also to run up the directory tree rebuilding each ancestor directory. Then I need to submit the top level directory in the commit.

I do have some code, but it is very chaotic at the moment, so I do not want to inflict it on StackOverflow.

If anyone could share any code that does this, it would be good. I am actually using Rust for this, but any language will do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was right...  I have coded up what I wrote above, and it seems to be working.